# varargs parameter list created at runtime

Tags: java, variadic-functions

```
public static void method(Set<?>... sets){}
```

Depending on program flow, above method is called with two sets, or with three sets, or more. (Not known at compile time).

Is there a way to constructing the argument list "on the fly"?
*sets* is of type *Set< ?>[ ]*

Following was **not** fruitful:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> varargs = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
```

(method recognizes varargs just as one set -> no solution)

```
Set<Integer>[] varargs = new HashSet<Integer>[2];
```

returns

```
"Cannot create generic array of HashSet<Integer>"
```

I would like to construct an array of arguments, while array size and content is filled at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Set<Integer>[] varargs = new HashSet[2];
 varargs[0] = new HashSet<Integer>() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe array of Set should be defined like this:

```
Set<Integer>[] varargs = new Set[2];
varargs[0] = new HashSet<Integer>();
varargs[1] = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know it was so obvious!